# Micorsoft.Data.SqlClient not working with Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity connections

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection, owin

I need to use Micorsoft.Data.SqlClient provider now in my existing project which was using System.Data.SqlClient DB provider.

We have added the library dll's from Nuget for Microsoft.Data.SqlClient already and also added the following lines in machine.config

```
<system.data> <DbProviderFactories> <add name="SqlClient Data Provider" invariant="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer" type="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" /> </DbProviderFactories> </system.data>
```

Our web.config for connection string is using now:

**providerName="Micorsoft.Data.SqlClient"**

Normal DB connection seems working fine with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient But,

we are getting error while using **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin** in line as:

```
AppUser = UserManager.FindByName(uname);
```

"The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Micorsoft.Data.SqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details."

Inner Exception as: "{"Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed."}".

Kindly suggest us the solution for this issue.

Thanks

Comment: You have a typo in the name. `Micorsoft.Data.SqlClient` should be `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: yes that's typo mistake. thanks, but now we are getting error as:
Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.

Comment: The new error suggests the aspnet identity package you are using expects `System.Data` instead of `Microsoft.Data`. I suggest you ask a new question for that issue.